# Point in unit square?

Tags: probability, algebra-precalculus

If a point selected at random in the unit square is known to be in the triangle bounded by $x = 0$ , $y = 0$ , and $x + y = 1$ , find the probabilty that it is also in the triangle bounded by $y = 0$ , $x = 1$ , and $x = y$.

I just started learning some probability on my own. Not much though. 
I was thinking though, would the probability be $1/2$ since there is a $50/100$ chance of getting $x = 1$ with $y = 0$?

Can someone please show me how to solve this problem? I tried drawing something but still came to the same conclusion. Is there another solution we can use to solve this problem. Can I please see it?

Comment: "how would you solve this problem"... By drawing a picture. (Note such a picture would show there is 0/100 chance of getting $x=y$.)

Answer (score 5):

**Hint:** The terms "given" or "known to be" are buzzwords -- they mean that you're talking about *conditional probability* here.

You can think of the problem this way: If I pick a uniformly random point in the first triangle (bounded by $x=0$, $y=0$, and $x+y=1$), what is the likelihood that the point ALSO lies in the second triangle?

In this case, all that it is really asking is this: what fraction of the area of the first triangle is shared with the second?

Comment: Would that still be 1/2 since it is bounded by x+y=1. There is 1/2 chance that it stays within that certain area given.

Comment: Yes, it would still be $\frac{1}{2}$.  In this case, it is because the first triangle has area $\frac{1}{2}$, and the part of that triangle that we are interested in has area $\frac{1}{4}$; hence the probability is $\frac{1/4}{1/2}=\frac{1}{2}$.